# glDrawElements Fails to draw

Tags: opengl, drawing, game-engine, lwjgl

I'm working on what will eventually be a terrain drawer, however at the moment I am just trying to get a basic pair of triangles to draw with glDrawElements. The code looks as such:

public class TerrainFlat extends AbstractTerrain {

```
IntBuffer ib = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(3);

 int vHandle = ib.get(0);
 int cHandle = ib.get(1);
 int iHandle = ib.get(2);

FloatBuffer vBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(19);
FloatBuffer cBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(18);
ShortBuffer iBuffer = BufferUtils.createShortBuffer(6);


@Override
public void initilize(){


    float[] vertexData = {50, 20, 100,      50, -20, 100,      10, -20, 100,             -10, -20, 100,     -50, -20, 100,     -50, 20, 100};
    float[] colorData = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,  0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 };
    short[] indexData = {0,1,2,3,4,5};

    vBuffer.put(vertexData);
    vBuffer.flip();


    cBuffer.put(colorData);
    cBuffer.flip();


    iBuffer.put(indexData);
    iBuffer.flip();

  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

  glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, iHandle);
  glBufferDataARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, iBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
  glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vHandle);
  glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);


  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, cHandle);
  glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, cBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);






}

@Override
public void setUp(float posX, float posY, float posZ){



}

@Override
public void draw(){

                   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glGenBuffersARB(ib);
  vHandle = ib.get(0);
  cHandle = ib.get(1);
  iHandle = ib.get(2);

  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vHandle);
  glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,  3 << 2 , 0L);
  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, cHandle);
  glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,  3 << 2  , 0L);
  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

  glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, iHandle);

  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0L);

  glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
  glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);


}

@Override
public void destroy(){
    ib.put(0, vHandle);
  ib.put(1, cHandle);
  ib.put(2, iHandle);
  glDeleteBuffersARB(ib);
} 



}
```

This does not draw anything, the screen is entirely black. GL_CULL_FACE is not enabled, and there is no lighting (or lack thereof) to cause this error. Moving the data binding into the  Draw() function lets it work (if you want I can add that code to this). This however means I create my buffer's every draw function (ie: bad). I'm wondering outright what I'm doing wrong here, because I've moved it around and slapped it silly for 4 days now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should not be generating new VBOs every time you draw. Not if you want them to use the data you generated in `initialize (...)`. I would seriously consider moving the call to `glGenBuffersARB (...)` into `initialize (...)`. That said, why are you using the ARB extension for buffer objects? They have been core since OpenGL 1.5.

Comment: I've solved it, once the 8 hours has past I'l post the solution.

Comment: Your buffer data stride should be zero in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting vHandle, cHandle and iHandle to 0.

You never need to create the IntBuffer in line 1 anyway.  Replace

```
 int vHandle = ib.get(0);
 int cHandle = ib.get(1);
 int iHandle = ib.get(2);
```

with

```
 int vHandle = glGenBuffers();
 int cHandle = glGenBuffers();
 int iHandle = glGenBuffers();
```

Comment: That will not fix the problem, because the OP is still generating new buffers every time `draw (...)` is called. Eventually the GL implementation is going to run out of names to give out, not that names to empty buffers do a lot of good in the first place. Part of the solution is to move non-whitespace lines 2-5 from `draw (...)` into `initialize (...)`.